# Check the length of integer variable

Tags: c#

Is there a way to check a lenth of integer variable, and if is to long just trim it.
I hava a field in database that accepts 3 character, lenth is 3.

So is it possible to do like it's done with string variable

example:

```
cust_ref = cust_ref.Length > 20 ? cust_ref.Substring(0, 19) : cust_ref;
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a field in a database that is storing an integer, why is it a character-type field, not an integer? The lazy answer here would be "4 bytes; an `int` is always 4 bytes".

Comment: $"{value}".Length

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The following worked a treat for me!

```
public static int IntLength(int i)
{
  if (i < 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
  if (i == 0)
    return 1;
  return (int)Math.Floor(Math.Log10(i)) + 1;
}
```

Original Source: http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Data-Types/Getthedigitlengthofanintvalue.htm

Comment: `var result = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Log10(Math.Abs(cust_ref)) + (cust_ref > 0 ? 1d : 2d))`

Answer (score 36):

The easiest answer would be:

```
//The length would be 3 chars.    
public int myint = 111;
myint.ToString().Length;
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to convert it to a string to make it shorter, that can be done numerically:

```
if (num > 999) {
  num %= 1000;
}
```

This will cut of digits from the left, if you want to cut them off from the right:

```
while (num > 999) {
  num /= 10;
}
```

If the value can be negative, also check:

```
if (num < -99) {
  num = -(-num % 100);
}
```

or:

```
while (num < -99) {
  num = -(-num / 10);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cust_ref = cust_ref.ToString().Length > 20 ? Convert.ToInt32(cust_ref.ToString().Substring(0, 19)) : cust_ref;
```

or simply use

```
cust_ref = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(cust_ref).Substring(0, 19));
```

Comment: Ok I got it, the key is to convert a variable to string.. Thanks!

Comment: The second version only works if the value *always* is at least 19 characters, otherwise you get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: int -> string -> string -> int :(

Answer (score 1):

Use like this

```
 cust_ref=   cust_ref.Tostring().Length > 20 ? Convert.ToInt32(cust_ref.ToString().Substring(0, 19)) : cust_ref;
```

Comment: This code will create 3 additional string instancies if it executes

Answer (score 1):

Nont very clear what you're asking for, but **as much as I unerstood** you're asking for:

```
int a = 1234567890;
```

for some reason you want to make it shorter, like

```
 int b = MakeShorter(a); 
    //b == 1234 (say)
```

If so, the easiest solution may be, convert it to string, made what you already implemented and reconvert it back to int.

If this is not what you're asking for, please clarify.

Comment: That it, if variable is to long I have to trim it, so first I have to convert it to string and then back to int?

Comment: @CrBruno: In **my** opinion this is an easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

The conversion to the string is ugly way to implement it.

It's require a pure math solution

```
int CutTheNumber(int number, int maxLen)
{
  var maxSize = (int)Math.Pow(10, maxlen);
  if(maxSize <= Math.Abs(number))
  {
    number %= maxSize;
  }

  return number;
}
```

Comment: No it doesn't *require* a numerical solution.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand you :(

Comment: You said that it *requires* a pure math solution, but that's not true. Other solutions work as well, it's just a matter of taste.

Comment: You are right all of them are working but they aren't working well! The strings' processing is so cost, it's critical to lot of applications until you are writing CD-ejector.

Comment: Then you should remove the costly floating point operation from your code. That would make it about ten times faster.

Comment: You can write test application and compare each solution if you need.

Comment: My PC is so busy now, I can't perform a clean test now.

Comment: Your code is the same as mine excepts the power calculation. But without power you can't do it universal. for(int i = 1; i < power; i++) maxValue *= 10 ?

Answer (score 0):

Checking length

```
     length = cust_ref.ToString().Length;
```

Remove extra bits

```
       if (length > need)
       {
           cust_ref =Convert.ToInt32( cust_ref.ToString().Remove(length -(length- need)));
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

for this u will have to do some simple stuffs.
like

```
cust_ref = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(cust_ref).Substring(0, 19));
```

or u can manually store it in any variable and the

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. use if else statement to check the validation ..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace avaragescore
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            float quiz;
            float midterm;
            float final;
            float avrg=0;
        Start:
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Quize Score here");
            quiz = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if(quiz > 100)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have entered wrong score please re-enter");
                goto Start;
            }
            Start1:
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Midterm Score here");
            midterm = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if(midterm > 100)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have entered wrong score please re- enter");
                goto Start1;
            }
            Start3:
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Final Score here");
            final = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if(final > 100)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have entered wrong Score Please re-enter");
                goto Start3;
            }
            avrg = (quiz + midterm + final) / 3;

            if(avrg >= 90)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your Score is {0} , You got A grade",avrg);
            }
            else if (avrg >= 70 && avrg < 90)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your Score is {0} , You got B grade", avrg);
            }
            else if (avrg >= 50 && avrg < 70)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your Score is {0} , You got C grade", avrg);
            }
            else if (avrg < 50)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Yor Score is {0} , You are fail", avrg);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You enter invalid Score");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When answering a question using code, it's good form to explain what the code is doing and *why* it answers the asker's question. Could you add some of that to your answer?